# I want to show alert message after record updation in laravel 8

Tags: alert, laravel-8

in Controller file:
return redirect()->route('show_record')->with('update', 'Content has been updated successfully!');

in View file:

```
@if(session('update'))
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable custom-success-box" style="margin: 15px;">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
    <strong> {{ session('update') }} </strong>
</div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got this sort of thing implemented on a number of site that I have built, and tend to use Noty for notifications as it's relatively simple to implement. Load it on every page, and in your controller, if you wish to return a message, do so.

In your controller :

```
    $notification = array(
        'message' => 'Message wording goes here',
        'alert-type' => 'success / danger / warning / info etc.'
    );
    return redirect()->route('your.route.here')->with($notification);
```

Then in your scripts section on the front of the site, after ensuring that you load Noty.js :

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var type = "{{ Session::get('alert-type', 'info') }}";
    var message = "{{ Session::get('message') }}";
    new Noty({
        text: message,
        type: type
    }).show();
});
</script>
@endif
```